# Outlook Dock badge count doesn't update until app has focus

Tags: ms-office, dock

I'm using Outlook for Mac (v16.49) on Big Sur (v11.3.1). Recently, I've found that the Outlook icon in the dock will only update the number of unread emails *after* the app has been given focus. During a working day I will occasionally glance to the Dock to see if new emails have arrived. Now, I need to periodically open Outlook in order to cause the Dock's badge icon to update.

How can I restore the original behaviour, i.e. having Outlook's Dock badge icon update automatically, rather than having to manually focus Outlook?

Comment: I have found a workaround – if Outlook is hidden using Cmd+H, rather than Cmd+W, this will cause the dock icon to remain up-to-date. But, in the past, hiding with Cmd+W would not prevent the badge count from updating.

Answer (score 2):

We're having the same issue at my office. Same version of Outlook. Latest Big Sur update.

Seems this is a common issue now. I can't seem to find any real solutions EXCEPT
If you're using the new Outlook layout, then switching back to the old one works. I did this now and I'm getting my badges in my Dock again.

Unfortunately this seems like the only solution until this bug is fixed...

Comment: As of today it's no longer possible to use the old layout.  And this bug is still not fixed.

Comment: Update: turns out it is still possible to use the old layout, but you have to let yourself get automatically updated to the new layout and then find the switch in the `outlook` menu to revert back.