# Outlook Dock badge count doesn't update unless app has focus

Tags: ms-office

I'm using Outlook for Mac (v16.55) on Big Sur and Monterey.
Recently, I've found that the Outlook icon in the dock will only update the number of unread emails after the app has been given focus.
So now I need to periodically open Outlook in order to cause the Dock's badge icon to update.

How can I restore the original behaviour, i.e. having Outlook's Dock badge icon update automatically, rather than having to manually focus Outlook?

Comment: Also asked here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420947/outlook-dock-badge-count-doesnt-update-until-app-has-focus